# Chrome not respecting hosts file entry

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I have used a method for years that has worked for me and limited any mysterious domain-based issues with cookies and such.

In my /etc/hosts file, I do the following for the local development version of www.mysite.com:

127.0.0.1 localhost local.mysite.com

When I visit http://local.mysite.com:3000, this has done exactly what you'd expect for years and years, and still works in Safari and Firefox. However, Chrome started stubbornly giving me an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED message a few months ago, and I can't make it work.  If I visit http://localhost:3000, it works fine, but I avoid developing against localhost for various reaions.  I have tried every possible thing I can find on the internet (clearing caches etc), and nothing has made the error go away.

Anyone have any idea what can be done here?

Answer (score -1):

In the browser, please clear host cache and then try it out. To clear host cache, follow the steps below

1. Open up Chrome browser and enter " chrome://net-internals/#dns " in the address bar without quotes
2. Click on the button *Clear host cache*
3. Restart your browser and try again

Comment: Actually similar setting worked for me - chrome://net-internals/#sockets and clicking "Flush socket pools"

Answer (score -1):

You need to disable the `dns prefetching and network condition` predicting services on chrome.

As chrome is trying to look for local.mysite.com in actual dns servers and not finding the local ip address.

You can see the below steps -

- Go to chrome://settings
- Click on "Show advanced settings..."
- Unmark the Predict network actions to improve page load performance
  box.
- Check if the DNS prefetching is really disabled by going to
  chrome://dns.
- You should see there something like DNS pre-resolution and TCP
  pre-connection is disabled.